# gradle: Skipping task ':compileJava' as it has no source files

Tags: java, build, compiler-errors, gradle

i try `gradle -d compileJava` in [my try project](https://github.com/roroco/try_gradle), and gradle raise "Skipping task ':compileJava' as it has no source files.". the worse thing is that i can't see anything created in build/. i create this project only with running `gradle init` and creating a "src/Ex.java".

**my question is:**

How to load default "compileJava" or define my "compileJava" to fix this warning.

Comment: of course, please see [my try project](https://github.com/roroco/try_gradle) i have commented out them

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By default, Java source files need to go into `src/main/java` (or `src/test/java` for test sources). Either adapt your directory structure accordingly, or reconfigure the source directory as follows:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["src"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's interesting that my file structure is actually correct, my java code **is** in `src/main/java`, but I have to add these lines to make `gradle build` work.

Comment: ``sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ["src"] ``
also works

Answer (score 1):

You can also change gradle version to 4.8 in

```
gradle-wrapper.properties 
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.8-bin.zip
```

then do:

```
./gradlew build
```