# Grails - Execution failed for task bootRun. A problem occurred starting process command java.exe

Tags: java, grails, build

There's an existing Grails project, and unfortunately all people who worked on it left the co.

When I do at windows 10 command prompt (not running as admin)

```
gradlew bootRun --debug
```

I see

```
...
09:01:21.398 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: STARTING
09:01:21.398 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Waiting until process started: command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin\java.exe'.
09:01:21.412 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: FAILED
09:01:21.412 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin\java.exe'' finished with exit value -1 (state: FAILED)
09:01:21.412 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter] Removed task artifact state for {} from context.
09:01:21.413 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':bootRun'
09:01:21.413 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] :bootRun FAILED
09:01:21.413 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :bootRun (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.214 secs.
09:01:21.413 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationWorkerRegistry] Worker root.8 completed (0 in use)
09:01:21.413 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]] finished, busy: 1.458 secs, idle: 0.0 secs
09:01:21.414 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
09:01:21.414 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
09:01:21.415 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
09:01:21.415 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
09:01:21.415 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
09:01:21.415 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin\java.exe''
09:01:21.415 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
09:01:21.415 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
09:01:21.415 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
09:01:21.415 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger]
09:01:21.415 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
09:01:21.415 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger]
...
```

I tried

```
gradlew clean build
```

like I saw recommended somewhere and it didn't help.

I looked at

```
java -version

java version "1.8.0_281"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.281-b09, mixed mode, sharing)
```

and

```
grails -version
| Grails Version: 4.0.0
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_291
```

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634000/gradle-skipping-task-compilejava-as-it-has-no-source-files) seems to think I should have a src/main/java in my project, but I don't have that dir.  How do I create/get it? I can't rebuild the project since it's huge. That article mentioned adding sourceSets somewhere, but it didn't say where to add it.

Any idea why it won't build and doesn't find java, and how to fix it?

In my windows 10 environment setup I see both system variables of java_home and java_jdk are set to:

```
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291
```

Update: Maybe this is the issue.  java -version shows 1.8.0_281.  Java home is 1.8.0_291.  How do I get java -version to show correct/installed version? I do have 1.8.0_291 in my Program files/Java dir.

Update2:
I tried creating gradle.properties file in home/me/.gradle dir with these contents, using double slashes because I had error and saw fix in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39010338/java-home-supplied-via-org-gradle-java-home-is-invalid-invalid-directory-us):

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_291
```

In my windows 10 command prompt window I ran and saw this error:

```
gradlew bootRun --debug
Changing state to: STARTING
12:39:02.908 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Waiting until process started: command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin\java.exe'.
12:39:02.910 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: FAILED
12:39:02.910 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin\java.exe'' finished with exit value -1 (state: FAILED)
12:39:02.910 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter] Removed task artifact state for {} from context.
12:39:02.910 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':bootRun'
12:39:02.910 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] :bootRun FAILED
12:39:02.911 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :bootRun (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.245 secs.
12:39:02.911 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationWorkerRegistry] Worker root.8 completed (0 in use)
12:39:02.911 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]] finished, busy: 1.989 secs, idle: 0.001 secs
12:39:02.919 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
12:39:02.919 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
12:39:02.919 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
12:39:02.919 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
12:39:02.919 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
12:39:02.919 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin\java.exe''
12:39:02.919 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
12:39:02.919 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
12:39:02.919 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
12:39:02.920 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger]
12:39:02.920 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
```

Still not sure what is causing error.  I tried with running command prompt as administrator, and see the same error.

Update3:

Trying this...I found build.gradle in grailsapp folder. for some reason Intellij Idea isn't showing it.  I added this

```
compileJava {
        options.fork = true 
        options.forkOptions.executable = '${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac.exe'
}
```

I still get the build failure

```
08:34:20.026 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin\java.exe'' finished with exit value -1 (state: FAILED)
08:34:20.026 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter] Removed task artifact state for {} from context.
08:34:20.027 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':bootRun'
08:34:20.027 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] :bootRun FAILED
08:34:20.027 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :bootRun (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.212 secs.
08:34:20.027 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationWorkerRegistry] Worker root.8 completed (0 in use)
08:34:20.027 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]] finished, busy: 1.528 secs, idle: 0.001 secs
08:34:20.028 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
08:34:20.028 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
08:34:20.029 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
08:34:20.029 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
08:34:20.029 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
08:34:20.029 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin\java.exe''
08:34:20.029 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
08:34:20.029 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
08:34:20.029 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
08:34:20.029 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger]
08:34:20.029 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
```

Update4:
stacktrace results:

```
gradlew bootRun --stacktrace
:compileJava NO-SOURCE
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:generateGitProperties UP-TO-DATE
:buildProperties UP-TO-DATE
:processResources
:classes
:findMainClass
:bootRun FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin\java.exe''

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:98)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$RunTasksAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:230)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$RunTasksAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:227)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:161)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:112)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:95)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:66)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin\java.exe''
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:198)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:329)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:86)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin\java.exe'
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WindowsProcessLauncher.start(WindowsProcessLauncher.java:22)
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcessLauncher.start(WrapperProcessLauncher.java:36)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:68)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin\java.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\mcleary\grailsapp"): CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
        ... 6 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.197 secs
```

Update5:
I have %JAVA_HOME%\bin in my path environment variable, but not java.exe specifically there. I don't think I've ever seen java.exe there.

Update6:
Looking at [pathingJar](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/gettingStarted.html), I'm adding

```
grails { pathingJar = true }
```

to build.gradle.  I'm not sure if I have to create a file too?

Comment: Can you share the relevant output from `./gradlew bootRun --stacktrace`? (maybe put it in a gist if it is really long).

Comment: Is the problem definitely that Java cannot be found?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown see update with stacktrace.  The problem is it can't start java.exe, not that it can't find java.

Comment: "The problem is it can't start java.exe, not that it can't find java." - Right.  I see the title of hte quesiton changed now.  Are you using pathingJar?

Comment: I don't know what pathingJar is

Comment: "I don't know what pathingJar is" - https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues?q=is%3Aissue+pathingJar+ or google search for "gradle pathingJar"

Comment: @JeffScottBrown - see update6.  I added something to my build.gradle.  I'm not sure if that's all that is needed.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown - I added pathing jar, but it's building forever.  Was I supposed to do other than what I have in the update6? It hasn't failed yet, so that's good...

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can try:

In gradle.properties in the .gradle directory in your HOME_DIRECTORY set org.gradle.java.home=/path_to_jdk_directory
or:

In your build.gradle

compileJava.options.fork = true
compileJava.options.forkOptions.executable = '/path_to_javac'

Comment: I found .gradle dir in c:/users/me/

Comment: there isn't a grade.properties file there.

Comment: there isn't a build.gradle there either.

Comment: See Update.  I'm not sure how to get Java -version to agree with Java_Home/installed version.

Comment: you have to create one gradle.properties file in the directory.

Comment: Thanks.  See update2.  It's still failing build.  See "finished with exit value -1" in update2.

Comment: any ideas? Should I create a compilejava.options.fork in .grails dir and add path_to_javac as well as the first thing?

Comment: @SatenderJoon- I noticed I have gradle.properties in my grailsapp project root dir.  Should I have added path_to_jdk there instead of my /c:/users/me ?

Comment: I added it in grailsapp project root dir too and still get the same build issue regarding exit value -1

Comment: As per these logs, I guess you have two different versions of Java installed. One is JRE - java version "1.8.0_281"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.281-b09, mixed mode, sharing)       and other is JDK - jdk1.8.0_291.

Comment: You can try removing the JRE and keep JDK. Also, please update the environment variable to point to the correct JDK.

Comment: I tried the compileJava options fork idea, and still get the same build failure.  See Updat3.

Comment: I had to install 281 for the timesheets here, and 291 was for oracle forms installation so I have to keep them

Comment: I tried removing 281 Java, closed command prompt I was building in, opened a new one, and still see the -1 error message. I also see ";C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin;C:\Program Files " in the build listing, so it's not wiped from somewhere.

Comment: I found in environment variable path some references to the 211 version, and removed it, opened a new command prompt, and still see the reference in the build failure. it's in CommonProgramFiles, but I'm not sure where it is.

Comment: I tried rebooting the computer but it's still showing the 211 java version in commonProgramfiles list, with the build failure.

Comment: I found one more place in the environmental setup for path with the other java version to remove. I don't see that one in the build debug info anymore, but it's still failing with the same message: Waiting until process started: command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin\java.exe'.
13:08:29.402 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: FAILED
13:08:29.402 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin\java.exe'' finished with exit value -1 (state: FAILED)
13:08:29.402 [DEBUG]

Comment: I guess now it is able to find the Java but the execution is breaking.

Comment: yes, it can't start java.exe

Comment: I tried uninstall/reinstall java as admin, checked java_home matched in env variables, ran powershell as admin and ran './gradlew bootRun --debug' but still get -1 error with problem starting java.exe.

Comment: Tried having someone with full admin acct login, ran powershell as admin, ran the './gradlew bootRun --debug' , but still had same -1 error where it start process command java.exe . It did go through more configuring steps and took longer but still had same error in the end.

Comment: I do not think the solution proposed here will fix the problem described in the question.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown The java not found issue went away...I think it was a remnant in my env variables of Windows. I'd appreciate any comments you have for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69527887/deprecated-gradle-features-were-used-in-this-build-making-it-incompatible-with

Answer (score 0):

If on windows try ./gradlew bootRun ( this solved my issue )